# What is the Function of new char[n+1]?

Tags: visual-c++

What is the function of `new char[n+1]` in the code fragment below. I have searched it everywhere but still I don't understand it.

**Code Fragment**

```
 n = strlen(t.name);
 a = new char[n+1];
 a = t.name;
 strcpy_s(name,a);
```

Comment: I get that in the start it's getting the length of name and in the end  a is copied to name. but what is new char doing.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi may be it was there but i was unable to understand. My bad!

Comment: And how is this related to "oop"?

Comment: @crashmstr actually i'm studying oop in c++ and this code came across while i was doing shallow and deep copy. Shallow copy is simple but deep copy i giving me a hard time

Comment: @HasanAfzal this code fragment is has nothing to do with Object Oriented programming. It is not even good C++ (C++ should be using `std::string` to hold strings, not C-style `char[]`).

Comment: @crashmstr i had to start from something. And thanks for the help i'll keep that in mind. 
Would you be kind enough to rewrite the fragment using std :: string?

Comment: `std::string a = t.name` it takes care of any memory needed as well as sizing.

Comment: @crashmstr is this how you were asking me to do???
asad (asad &a)
{
 cout<<"Copy Constructor is Called: ";
std :: string n = a.name;
n = name;
std :: string e = a.id;
e = id;
cout<<"iD copied"<<endl;
}

Comment: @HasanAfzal without knowing the context of the fragment or what you just posted, I have no idea. Replace `char*` with `std::string`, replace `char[1024]` with `std::string`, assign to `std::string` using `=`. Basic modern C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving behind all the issues with this code, strings in C are NULL-terminated. So, when you want to copy a string into an array you should reserve an extra character for the trailing `0`, hence the `+ 1`.

As for the "what does the `new` operator do", one of many many many [possible references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new):

> Allocates requested number of bytes. These allocation functions are called by new-expressions to allocate memory in which new object would then be initialized.

Comment: Strings in C++ are `std::string` and you don't have to worry about any `+1` :)

Comment: @crashmstr That's why I wrote "Leaving behind all the issues with this code" :-) But you're right, it's rather a C thing.